# 12359.948369 systemd-shoutdown[1] wating for process crond

Tags: 20.04, shutdown

My ubuntu 20.04 is taking 10-15 mins to shut down. Is any issue with my ubuntu? If yes, then how to overcome this issue?

Memory - 16GB RAM, 1TB SSD

Edited -
After running this command `sudo journalctl  -b -1 -e`, [here is result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lZcR.png)

```
Jan 30 23:05:51 ubuntu systemd[1]: Reached target Shutdown.
Jan 30 23:05:51 ubuntu systemd[1]: Reached target Final Step.
Jan 30 23:06:49 ubuntu systemd[1]: plymouth-poweroff.service: Start-post operation timed out. Stopping.
Jan 30 23:06:49 ubuntu systemd[1]: plymouth-poweroff.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
Jan 30 23:06:49 ubuntu systemd[1]: Failed to start Show Plymouth Power Off Screen.
```

Comment: After rebooting, use `sudo journalctl  -b -1 -e` to see the shutdown log. See what's taking so long.

Comment: Can you try for test in `/etc/default/grub`  Line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` change to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""` and run `sudo update-grub` Make a backup from the file before.